# How to know if a text in a div/span will overflow before rendering into DOM

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, reactjs, dom

I am having a `div`/`span` which will be rendered into DOM. I am also having a css style to the `div` to have overflow hidden and show ellipses. I want to know before drawing the div whether the overflow occurs or not. Is there a way find it?

I have seen that by comparing `clientWidth` and `scrollWidth` we can know if overflow occurs or not but that can be figured after element is rendered. But I want it before rendering.

React Code:

```
<div className="element">
     <span>{this.props.name}</span>
</div>
```

css style:

```
. element{
     overflow: hidden;
}

> span {
    overflow: hidden;
    text-overflow: ellipsis;
    max-width: 100%;
}
```

document.getElementsByTagName("span").clientWidth is greater than width given by canvas in below width

var c=document.getElementById("myCanvas");
var ctx=c.getContext("2d");
**ctx.measureText(this.props.name).width**

Is there any way to get above two values nearly same.

Comment: [Canvas's measureText()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/measureText) method maybe helpful here.

Comment: I never heard about that... If the client resize the browser during the rendering ?

Comment: @abhishekkannojia with out canvas element this doent work?

Comment: Do i need to create element with canvas for using this method

Comment: Yeah, you need to create a dummy `canvas` and then measure the text there.

Comment: @abhishekkannojia is there a way to get the size the span of the text that occupies the width rather than just the text width

As i am seeing a 10px difference between the text size and after rendering the text to dom in width

Comment: I have updated my question